# HttpURLConnection very slow compared to equivalent iOS implementation

Tags: android, xml, performance, network-programming

I'm writing an app for both iOS and Android, and both are native (no PhoneGap, no Titanium). The app's general behavior is to GET an XML file from a server, parse it, and based on its contents GET some number of other XML files as well as to download some extra data files ( PDFs, images, etc ). It's a bit like RSS.

An initial load on iOS (when I've cleared local caches so everything has to be pulled down) takes about 20 seconds. Less than 1 second for the main feed, and 19 or 20 for the rest of the content.

On Android, it takes about **two minutes**.

Now, early on I found that XML parsing was a big hit so I dropped XmlPullParser and wrote a SAX parser which sped things up a bit (one XML file went from 20 seconds to parse down to 2, which is still really slow compared to iOS). But still, now that XML parsing is less of a factor in performance, the network performance is killing me.

I've googled and found a lot of threads on exactly this. I've tried a bunch of different approaches, none of which have done anything and it feels like guesswork more than engineering.

For example, I've done this:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

And on my HttpURLConnection, I've set it to use NO_PROXY and a shorter connect timeout, and to disallow caches.

```
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
c.setConnectTimeout(1000);
c.setUseCaches(false);
```

None has helped!

Clearly, Android's network stack works and it works quickly - various Android apps I've used that touch the network are perfectly quick. So clearly I'm doing something wrong. But what?

**Please, help. I'm at wit's end here.**

Comment: Use Traceview to determine precisely where your problem lies.

Comment: Disabling caches is counterproductive if you want performance.

Comment: @CommonsWare DDMS's network view shows me what I can see from logs - downloads have high bandwidth, but there's high latency between them (or maybe before they start as the connection begins). It doesn't actually tell me very much, but I confess I might not be using it correctly.

Comment: @EJP That's what I figured but dozens of posts I've seen here have suggested disabling caching for exactly this problem.

Comment: "DDMS's network view" -- I suggested that you use Traceview. Traceview != the network tab.

Comment: @CommonsWare OK, can you help me then? When I googled for Traceview I found that DDMS is what has replaced it. When I ran trace view on the command line I was told to use tools/monitor. monitor took me to DDMS. Since this is a network issue, I assumed the network view of DDMS. So, what in DDMS helps me to find and resolve this problem?

Comment: "So, what in DDMS helps me to find and resolve this problem?" -- Traceview helps you find and resolve this problem. https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTools/article.html http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkN1ed35314 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dgnx0E7m1GQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not *solved* the problem, but I've worked out what's going on. **It was latency.**

1. Android's HttpURLConnection apparently has a broken http keep-alive implementation
2. Maybe related to the above problem, http pipelining doesn't work either

I was synchronously making URL connections in a single AsyncTask - I tried various approaches to speed it up like doing all my connections one after another, saving their response bodies in memory and processing that later. That sped it up from 2 or 3 minutes seconds to about 1.5, but that was still unacceptable.

In a last desperate hope I tried [AsyncHttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

And holy smokes, now the whole download takes about 20 seconds, just like it does on iOS.

So, word to the wise: If your android app makes a LOT of GETs to a service, and you can't rewrite that service to elide those GETs into a single big batch ( I couldn't here ) you **do not** want to use Android's HttpUrlConnection. Use AsyncHttpClient.

Unfortunately, AsyncHttpClient is structured like AFNetworking, which is a lot more awkward on Java than it is in ObjectiveC. So it will take some finagling. But it works really well.